# Custom objective function for xgboost to optimize lift in best decile

Tags: xgboost, objective-function

I've tried to define a custom objective function for xgboost to optimize the lift for a binary classification problem in the upper decile.  The task is simply to concentrate the training effort to the (say) 10% of data points that are the easiest to predict correctly. The problem is also formulated for a practical case here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202438/optimizing-cumulative-lift-in-classification.  I'm not sure if this is a well defined problem, but in any case, my idea is to sort the scores, pick out the best 10% and concentrate the cost function to those.  The sorting and cutoff are however non-differentiable, so I use the fast soft sort algorithm (https://github.com/google-research/fast-soft-sort) together with a smooth Heaviside function instead.  Then I can compute the Jacobian, but it seems perhaps the Hessian is not defined for the soft sort.  This is as far as I've got:

```
import numpy as np
from fast_soft_sort.numpy_ops import soft_rank

def smooth_heaviside(x, smooth=0.3, offset=0.):
    return 1./(1. + np.exp(-(1./smooth)*(x-offset)))

def smooth_heaviside_derivative(x, smooth=0.05, offset=0.): # offset should be set to the fraction above which to optimize the lift
    f = smooth_heaviside(x, smooth=smooth, offset=offset)
    return (1./smooth)*f*(1.-f)

def compute_cost_and_jacobian(y_pred, y_label, smooth=0.001, frac=0.8, reg_strength=1.):
    N = y_pred.shape[0]
    sr = fast_soft_sort.numpy_ops.SoftRank(y_pred, regularization_strength=reg_strength)
    R = sr.compute() # rank
    Hs = smooth_heaviside(R/N, smooth, frac)
    C = -sum(Hs*y_label)
    Hs_d = smooth_heaviside_derivative(R/N, smooth, frac)
    Cj = -sr.jvp((1./N)*Hs_d*y_label)
    return C, Cj

def smooth_rank_lift(y_true, y_pred):
    C, Cj = compute_cost_and_jacobian(y_pred, y_true, smooth=0.2, frac=0.8, reg_strength=0.0001)
    grad = Cj
    hess = 0*Cj # ?
    print(np.mean(grad))
    return grad, hess
```

But using this as the argument for 'objective' with the XGBClassifier fails to produce anything but the initial guess with predict_proba (I’m not very experienced with xgboost).  I'm guessing a lot of things may be wrong here, but does this seem like a viable approach?  Any other ways of solving this problem?